# Binary Search Tree Recursive to Iterative version

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I currently have this recursive version of an insert method to a Binary Search Tree. I am trying to get the same results now, but I want it to be an iterative version. I think I am pretty close, if someone could just give me some advice as to what else I need to do to get this working as I am stumped at this point.

Recursive:

```
public void insert(E item)
  {
    root = insert(root, item, 0); 
  }

  private BNode insert(BNode ptr, E item, int d)
  {
    if (ptr == null) {
     ++Size;
     return new BNode(item, null, null, d);
  }


   int diff = item.compareTo(ptr.data);
   if (diff < 0)
   ptr.left = insert(ptr.left, item, d+1);
   else if (diff > 0)
   ptr.right = insert(ptr.right, item, d+1);
   else
   ; // duplicates;

   return ptr; 
 }
```

My Current Code for Iterative version:

```
public void insert(E item)
{
  BNode ptr = root;
  int d = 0; // set the initial depth

  if(ptr == null) {
     ++Size;
     root = new BNode(item, null, null, d); 
   } 

   while(ptr != null) {
      int diff = item.compareTo(ptr.data);
      if(diff < 0) 
         ptr.left = new BNode(item, null, null, d+1); // *EDIT
      else if (diff > 0){
         ptr.right = new BNode(item, null, null, d+1);  //*EDIT
      }
      else
       break;  // no duplicates

      }
      ++Size;
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc my version will not compile when I run a test on it. The items are not getting inserted into the tree. I am lost as to what the problem is?

Comment: Just to help you ask your questions better: In questions like this people should first trace your code to face the error or problem themselves and then try to solve it! So this makes your question quite less attractive and you may don't get the answer you need, at least in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 0):

> @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc my version will not compile when I run a test
>   on it. The items are not getting inserted into the tree. I am lost as
>   to what the problem is?

You are posting contradicting points.  If it cannot compile it, then how did you run it?  I'm assuming you can compile it.

You never actually add a new node except for root node.  You want to change up your while loop.  Once you find a null spot, then you should put the new node there.  Then break the loop.

```
   while(ptr != null) {
      int diff = item.compareTo(ptr.data);
      if(diff < 0) 
         ptr = ptr.left;
      else{
         ptr = ptr.right;
      }

      //update this code here
      if(ptr == null){
          ptr = new BNode(item, null, null, d);
          ++Size;
          break;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have reworded my question better. When it comes to adding the new node to the null spot would I be doing something similar to this "BNode node = new BNode(ptr.left, item, d+1); " ?

Comment: Yes.  You want to do something like that but to the `ptr` object.

Comment: I updated my code above.. I am now getting a better output, but I am still not getting the correct results for the size of the tree as well as some the the depths. I think this may have something to do with my else statement? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also it is not correctly adding the nodes towards the bottom of the tree :( I am stuck.

Comment: That's a separate issue.  I'd recommend debugging through and see what conditions you are missing.  Make sure you are properly tracking the depth variable.  What are you doing in duplicate cases?  What if you have an item that is same value as an already inserted node...what do you do then?  Think about all the possibilities.  Try drawing it out.  Don't give up every time you're stuck.  Just breathe and try a new approach.